# Drawing a partial circle using SVG arcs

Tags: javascript, svg, graphics, geometry

I want to draw a partial arc using SVG. According to the [docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands), the centre of the circle is calculated automatically. But my arc overflows the circle. It is easier to demonstrate it with a picture:

`<svg width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="border: navy solid 1px;">
  <g transform="translate(10 10) scale(0.5 0.5)">
  <path d="M0 50 A1 1 0 0 1 100 50 Z" fill="blue"></path>
  <path d="M0 50 A1 1 0 0 1 50 0 Z" fill="purple" opacity="0.7"></path>
  </g>
</svg>`

[image: SVG Arc overlapping a half circle]

Here is the link to the [codepen](https://codepen.io/bmamouri/pen/Mqxggv?editors=1000) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw arcs before blue circle (as I draw red one)  or make redrawing of circle segment (the last line - I made it green to emphasize but must be blue). So combination of circle arc + segment gives moon crescent form

```
 <path d="M50 50 L50 0 A1 1 0 0 1 100 50 Z" fill="red" opacity="0.7"></path>
 <path d="M0 50 A1 1 0 0 1 100 50 Z" fill="blue"></path>
 <path d="M0 50 A1 1 0 0 1 50 0 Z" fill="purple" opacity="0.7"></path>
 <path d="M50 0 A50 50 0 0 0 0 50 Z" fill="green"></path>
```

Comment: Looks much better. I am wondering what I was doing wrong? Why putting rx=ry=1 gives a larger circle?

Comment: I am not specialist in SVG and was surprised how `rx,ry=1,1` does work (don't see clear explanation in specification - they all discuss only sweep/large flags in details).

Comment: [MDN Paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths): "If the start->end points are farther than the ellipse's x and y radius can reach, the ellipse's radii will be minimally expanded so it could reach the start->end points"